# Is it possible to overload a thread using ISynchronizeInvoke.BeginInvoke()?

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

My problem is this:

I have two threads, my UI thread, and a worker thread. My worker thread is running in a seperate class that gets instantiated by the form, which passes itself as an `ISynchronizeInvoke` to the worker class, which then uses `Invoke` on that interface to call it's events, which provide status updates to the UI for display. This works wonderfully.

I noticed that my background thread seemed to be running slowly though, so I changed the call to `Invoke` to `BeginInvoke`, thinking that "I'm just providing progress updates, it doesn't need to be exactly synchronous, no harm done" except that now I'm getting oddities with the progress update. My progress bar updates, but the label's text doesn't, and if I change to another window and try to change back, it acts like the UI thread is locked up, so I'm wondering if perhaps my progress calls (which happen very often) are overloading the UI thread so much that it never processes messages. Is this possible at all, or is there something else at work here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're definitively overloading the UI thread.

In your first sample, you were (behind the scenes) sending a message to the UI thread, waiting for it to be processed (that's the purpose of invoke, which ultimately relies on [SendMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644950%28VS.85%29.aspx)), and then sending another one. In the meantime, other messages were probably enqueued (WM_PAINT messages, for example) and processed.

In your second sample, by using BeginInvoke (which ultimately relies on [PostMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644944%28VS.85%29.aspx)), you massively enqueued a lot of messages in the message queue, that the message pump must sequentially handle. And of course, while it's handling those thousands of messages, it cannot handle the OS messages (WM_PAINT, etc..) which makes your UI look "frozen"

You're probably providing too much status updates ; try to lower the feedback level.

If you want to understand better how messages work in windows, [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644927%28VS.85%29.aspx) is the place to start.

Answer (score 1):

A few thoughts;

- try batching your updates; for example, there is no point updating for *every* iteration in a loop; depending on the speed, perhaps every 50 / 500. In the case of lists, you would buffer in a local list variable, take the list over via `Invoke` / `BeginInvoke`, and process the buffer on the UI thread
- variable capture; if you are using `BeginInvoke` and anonymous methods, you could have problems... I'll add an example below
- making the UI update efficient - especially *if* you are processing a list; some controls (especially list-based controls) have a pair of methods like `BeginEdit` / `EndEdit`, that stop the UI redrawing when you are making lots of updates; instead, it waits until the `End*` is called

capture problem... imagine (worker):

```
List<string> stuff = new List<string>();
for(int i = 0 ; i < 50000 ; i++) {
    stuff.Add(i.ToString());
    if((i % 100) == 0) {
        // update UI
        BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker) delegate {
            foreach(string s in stuff) {
                listBox.Items.Add(s);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Did you notice that at some point both threads are talking to `stuff`? The UI thread can be iterating it while the worker thread (which has kept running past `BeginInvoke`) keeps adding. This can cause issues. Not usually *performance* issues (unless you are catching the exceptions and taking a long time to log them), but definitely issues. Options here would include:

- using `Invoke` to run the update synchronously
- create a new buffer per update, so that the two threads never have the same list instance (you'd need to look very carefully at the variable scoped to make sure, though)